# Android back stack - Go back to a certain activity in back stack

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

I have activities A -> B -> C -> D. How can I open the existing B from activity D clearing C and D? I would end up with A -> B. I don't want to recreate a new B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must use [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).

According to the doc:

> consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls
>   startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of
>   activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given
>   Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.
>
> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will
>   either receive the new intent you are starting here in its
>   onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new
>   intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the
>   default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same
>   intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch
>   modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be
>   delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

Comment: This is the correct answer. When starting Ativity B from activity D, add these 2 flags. This will give you the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare you target activity's(Activity B in your situation) Mode of SingleTop in Manifest file like

```
<activity android:name="YourActivityName" android:launchMode="singleTop"></activity>
```

Then startActivity for navigating to this Activity will end C and D and wont start a new Activity B

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing any difference.

Comment: how about  <activity android:name="YourActivityName" android:launchMode="singleTask"></activity>

Answer (score 0):

Right after you finish dealing with C and D, you can just `finish()` the activities.

Comment: As the question says, I call B from D. I don't exit D and C to get to B.

Comment: Oh sorry I miss-read in that case you just need to add a callback to Activity B and use resume the state of the activity

Comment: Can you elaborate on "add a callback to Activity B"? By "use resume the state of the activity", you mean onResume()?